# Python Discord Bot aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorSSLError exception

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

With this code on python 3.6.6:

```
import discord


client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('/'):
        await message.channel.send('Got command')

client.run('Njk1*******************************************************')
```

I end up with a really long traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 804, in create_connection
    sock, protocol_factory, ssl, server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 830, in _create_connection_transport
    yield from waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 505, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 201, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:841)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eric/Desktop/ Python_Files/lib/discordbot/discordbot.py", line 21, in <module>
    client.run('Njk1*******************************************************')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 165, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 483, in _request
    timeout=real_timeout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 859, in _create_connection
    req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 986, in _create_direct_connection
    req=req, client_error=client_error)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 941, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorSSLError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorSSLError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:default [[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:841)]
```

Can anyone help me fix this?
It might be a problem with my system because I searched up some other tutorials online and none of them worked and my internet connection is fine.
(I couldn't code block the first part of the exception because it has "too much code")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificates were not installed so I ran `Install Certificates.command` and that fixed the certificate error. This is the file contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 << "EOF"

# install_certifi.py
#
# sample script to install or update a set of default Root Certificates
# for the ssl module.  Uses the certificates provided by the certifi package:
#       https://pypi.org/project/certifi/

import os
import os.path
import ssl
import stat
import subprocess
import sys

STAT_0o775 = ( stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
             | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
             | stat.S_IROTH |                stat.S_IXOTH )

def main():
    openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(
        ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)

    print(" -- pip install --upgrade certifi")
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,
        "-E", "-s", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "certifi"])

    import certifi

    # change working directory to the default SSL directory
    os.chdir(openssl_dir)
    relpath_to_certifi_cafile = os.path.relpath(certifi.where())
    print(" -- removing any existing file or link")
    try:
        os.remove(openssl_cafile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    print(" -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle")
    os.symlink(relpath_to_certifi_cafile, openssl_cafile)
    print(" -- setting permissions")
    os.chmod(openssl_cafile, STAT_0o775)
    print(" -- update complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
EOF
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! But I wonder what caused this in the first place?

Comment: It's because the default python installation doesn't include the needed certificates to actually get a handshake+connection with discord api